# is null space of Triadiagonal matrices empty?

Tags: matrices

I have generated many random tridiagonal matrices  and I considered that the null space of all of them is empty. Is this true for all tridiagonal matrices?

Comment: A null space may  be the zero space, but is never empty.

Comment: Hint: what are the odds that one of your "random" tridiagonal matrices has a non-zero determinant?

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you. I guess I need to build it not generating randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. For a nontrivial example consider
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks. I guess in general, for random matrices, the null space is empty. I have generated hundreds of matrices, the null space of all of them was empty

Comment: @MamaD What do you mean by that? Couldn't you have come across the above matrix if you randomly generated them?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch you are right, this is an example which rejects the title. I have generated about 4000 symmetric tridiagonal random matrices and all of them had empty null space. I didn't come across the matrix given as solution.

Comment: @MamaD I see what you mean; I have added an explanation for this phenomenom below

Answer (score 1):

[@mechanodroid](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/144766/) has already provided a counter-example. I want to comment on why you didn't come accross any tri-diagonal matrices that have a non-trivial null space:

Note that the null space of a matrix $A$ equals $\{0\}$ if and only if the $A$ is not invertible). [However, the Lebesgue measure (on $\Bbb R^{(n^2)}$) of the set of non-invertible $n\times n$ matrices is $0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872323/if-i-generate-a-random-matrix-what-is-the-probability-of-it-to-be-singular/1872332)

A similar thing happens if you construct a Lebesgue measure (on $\Bbb R^{3n-2}$) only for tri-diagonal matrices. So, informally (since the Lebesgue measure is not at all a probability measure), the probability of randomly choosing a tri-diagonal matrix with non-trivial null-space is $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is perfect, I wish I could accept two answers